# Virtual CDrom Methods? (Like the old U3 sandisk hack)

Tags: usb, boot, dvd

It sucks because I used to have a sandisk U3 and now... /shrug

To the point then, 
Ive been trying to find a cheap way to emulate a CD/DVD/BDrom through USB.
The U3 USB drive I had, let me write an ISO to the USB, and it would read in the bios as a CDROM.

Not as a “bootable disk”, not as a FDD, it read “CD-ROM”
(Just clarifying)

So if anyone knows a way to do this, a current model USB stick that has an abusable virtual CD layer, Or the proper name for such a device (so I can google it) your assistance is most welcome.
Thankyou.

Comment: so you mean you want to make your usb bootable with any os you want right?

Comment: a way to boot from usb without second bootloader, yes.

Comment: you can try using same pendrive to boot multiple boot cds and os by using same pd ... tools like yumi,universal usb installer,sardu can help you please google them

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: Isnt PDL built with grub?

Comment: ya it uses grub ..

Comment: It would be the right answer if I was looking for something to install just an OS, but what i need is a way to trick incompatible software into thinking its booting from a physical drive.

Comment: what do you mean by incompatible software?ok if this is what you are finding http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/SuperGRUB2Disk